# Find the right parameter through a brute force algorithm

Tags: matlab, brute-force

I have realized a compression algorithm, suppose that I exec it, calling:

```
myCompression(data, th)
```

*th* parameter is a real number between 0 and 1. Sometimes this can be really small number, for example 212.19e-013.

```
num = length(myCompression(data, th))
```

gave me the number of data remains after compression. If I want *num* to be bigger, I need to choose a lower *th* parameter. Viceversa, if I want higher *num*, I have to choose lower *th*.

Now the problem is: I want to find a proper *th* such that *num* is equal to a target number that I choose.
As you know, find *th* is really long work, and I would realize a brute force algorithm that finds *th* that satisfy my need. I've write this:

```
target = 304;
th = 2.49e-011;
num = 0;

while(num~=target)    
    num = length(MCSimplify3(time, latitudes, longitudes, th));
    disp(horzcat('tol: ', num2str(th), ' num: ', num2str(num)));

    if (num>target)
        th = th+(rand()*th);
    else
        th = th-(rand()*th);
    end

    th = abs(th);
end
```

The previous script start but never catch the target. The problem, I suppose, is due the fact that added or subtracted `(rand()*th)` is too big, so one time is above the target, and one time is below. So continue to swinging, and never catch the result, as you can see here:

```
tol: 2.67e-012 num: 333
tol: 4.0685e-012 num: 303
tol: 2.9909e-012 num: 320
tol: 3.1953e-012 num: 316
tol: 4.5895e-012 num: 298
tol: 3.7916e-012 num: 308
tol: 3.8906e-012 num: 308
tol: 7.6049e-012 num: 257
tol: 4.3302e-012 num: 299
tol: 1.6646e-013 num: 624
tol: 2.9337e-013 num: 562
tol: 2.9553e-013 num: 561
tol: 4.965e-013 num: 503
tol: 8.47e-013 num: 448
tol: 1.3934e-012 num: 391
tol: 2.163e-012 num: 350
tol: 2.6348e-012 num: 335
tol: 4.6699e-012 num: 296
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

First, draw a graph of the data you've shown us.  That should give you a clear idea of where to direct your search for a value of `th` which gives you the target value you seek.

Second, implement some kind of search through values of `th` in the right range; even a simple bisection search of an interval bracketing the desired target value will be better than your current approach.

Just eyeballing your data suggests that, for the target value of `304`, the value for `th` should lie in the range `(3.7916e-012,4.0685e-012)`.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I would, brute forcing shrinking the interval of tolerance. But clearly something goes wrong.

Comment: @Mariano: it's not apparent from your code that this is exactly what you are doing.  I don't understand the use of `rand` (which I take to be a random number generator) at all.  Nor do I understand your constant use of `brute force`.

Comment: My idea was to add (or substract) a little numeric amount to the threshold. Since I don't know in advice how much this amount is big I generate it randomly, I know that this isn't a good idea, but in the meanwhile I can't think the best.

Comment: @Mariano: I wrote 'bisection', I repeat 'bisection'.  If you don't know what I mean, Google.

Answer (score 1):

there are more then one way to skin your cat, and the first thing you need to do it remove `rand`, as it is a highly unpredictable parameter. That being said, I refer you to [Nelder-Mead](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nelder%E2%80%93Mead_method).

From a more practical perspective, you should replace rand() with either a constant (e.g. 0.1), or a variable that measures the distance between num and target multiplied by a varying parameter.

Alternatively, you can use minimization routines like fminsearch (which uses Nelder-Mead) with possibly some small tweaks for the discontinuities.

It's hard to give more info without being able to run code (i.e. I need MCSimplify3).

Answer (score 0):

With precious tips of High Performance Mark, this is how I resolved.

```
target = 304;
len = 0;

a = 0;
b = 1;

while(len~=target)
    c = (a+b)/2;
    len = length(MCSimplify3(time, latitudes, longitudes, c));
    if(len<target)
        b = c;
    end
    if (len>target)
        a = c;
    end
    if (len==target)
        disp(horzcat('tol: ', num2str(th), ' num: ', num2str(len)));
    end
end
```